# Does locking on a Semaphore object make any sense?

Tags: c#, locking, semaphore

I came across a code which used Semaphores as lock objects. I asked my co-workers about it and they said, it could be meaningful, if we wanted to monitor the state of our locks, or if a weird exception happened deep in the code and the CLR could not rolling back the stack, or something like that, and the lock is not released properly, we can release it manually.

I never heard about these phenomenons, and found nothing about these, so I'm very skeptical about this whole thing. I see this only as a bad practice, because you will be confused how to use the Semaphore object. Someone can confirm this?

```
private Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(0, 1);

public void DoSomethingThreadSafe()
{
    lock (_semaphore)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: `lock` is translated to calls to `Monitor`. Even if solar storms cause the program to not release the lock, you can't release it with the Semaphore. Is there any code in the project, that accesses the semaphore in another way?

Comment: A lock allows only one thread to enter the part that's locked and the lock is not shared with any other processes. A mutex is the same as a lock but it can be system wide (shared by multiple processes). ..

Comment: Locking a semaphore as itself is not different to locking any other type of object. Of course using the semaphore as intended (WaitOne/Release) directly inside the lock is meaningless as it defeats the purpose of the semaphore. I guess that depends on what happens inside the lock and whether the semaphore is accessed and used in any other manner in the system.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same feelings, thanks for reinforcing. Only once was called Release() on the semaphore in a function, but nothing used that. Maybe it would not worked anyway. I refactored the code, and made these Semaphores into objects. I was just curious, whether it _could_ have some meaning after all, in an other application, but it seems not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking on a semaphore object doesn't give any additional benefits comparing to any other object type but may compromise the readability as it's not an idiomatic way to do such things:

> if we wanted to monitor the state of our locks

The `lock` mechanism is absolutely agnostic to an object type used for synchronization and doesn't make any attempts to distinguish a `Semaphore` instance from another instance in order to perform some `Semaphore`-specific actions. What actually happens, the `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` methods are used in the generated code for the `lock` construction and these methods internally work with an CLR object header (which is part of any reference type memory layout) and/or sync block which is an entry in special table referenced by instance header. So there is no way to monitor state of an object used for synchronization apart from hacky approaches to obtain internal synchronization state maintained by CLR.

> or if a weird exception happened deep in the code and the CLR could not rolling back the stack, or something like that, and the lock is not released properly, we can release it manually

Again, the state of a semaphore as a `Semaphore` instance has nothing to do with state of a synchronization object which just happened to be a part of the semaphore instance memory layout and which is used internally by `lock` mechanism, and entering or leaving `lock` block doesn't lead to changing the semaphore count as well as releasing the semaphore does not have any influence on synchronization object used for `lock`. So using a semaphore doesn't give any benefits in such situation and moreover if things go wrong in the way when CRL isn't able to unwind the stack, it's very doubtful that an application code can do something in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Semaphores and Mutexes, do have an advantage when you are trying to achieve exclusive access to a resource across process boundaries. Both classes have c'tors that take `String` parameters. If two (or more) processes use the same `String` value, you can achieve exclusive access to a resource. (Obviously, this exclusivity is "voluntary in that you have to program for it).

These classes can ensure only one thread within a single process has access to whatever resource you're interested in.